# How to manage the role wise functionalities in grails application (custom authorization)

Tags: grails3

I am developing an application using Grails framework. I would like to allow access to the application to Users based on their Roles and the privileges granted to those Roles. Spring Security can provide only high-level security. which is not sufficient to my task. But here I would like to manage the privileges dynamically.
Please suggest any best approach to do this. 
Suppose take a Reprint functionality in application. Being an Admin will decide to who can access and who cannot based on their Roles.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring security provides the role based functionality which is not dynamic or admin or any super your can't allow / deny the access to the particular thing dynamically to the particular user.

But you could create the custom authorization workflow.
Assuming that you have 'user' table in your database, in this table you can create the one column as 'authorization' as a string / varchar data.

Make a JSON as follows ( for example)

```
[ "resource1":{
   "canView" : true,
   "canEdit" : false,
   "canDelete" : false
  },

 "resource2":{
   "canView" : true,
   "canEdit" : true,
   "canDelete" : true
  }
]
```

Create / build  this JSON as per your requirement, this is just an example.
Store this as a string in the database convert it after fetching from backend ( String to JSON) manipulate its values dynamically (which admin will change), again convert to string and update it, fetch and convert to JSON and check value wherever you want check -> Is the user have an access to get this resource or not.

Comment: Thanks a lot Nitin